# How to check for blank elements in XML?

Tags: regex, xml, tags

Is there a regex to check for empty elements for the XML below? So I want to check whether or not everything below the `<ClientRequest>` tags are populated or not?

```
<Response xmlns="http://Test/Types"> 
 <ClientRequest>
    <Name>TEST</Name>
    <Id><222/Id>
    <Parameters>
      <SID>123456</SID>
    </RequestParams>
    <StartDate>2017-10-13T23:00:01.000+01:00</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2017-10-14T22:59:59.000+01:00</EndDate>
    <URL></URL>
  </ClientRequest>
  <Install/>
  <Types/>
  <LR/>
  <Package/>
  <Services/>
  <Issues/>
  <Complaints/>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an XML parser or XPath, not regex, to check or parse XML.

This XPath,

```
//*[not(text()) and not(*)]
```

will select all elements that have ***no text or element children***.

This XPath,

```
//*[not(node())]
```

will select all ***empty*** elements (also disallowing comment and PI children).

Note that your XML is not well-formed.  Here it is with corrections:

```
<Response xmlns="http://Test/Types"> 
 <ClientRequest>
    <Name>TEST</Name>
    <Id>222</Id>
    <Parameters>
      <SID>123456</SID>
    </Parameters>
    <StartDate>2017-10-13T23:00:01.000+01:00</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2017-10-14T22:59:59.000+01:00</EndDate>
    <URL></URL>
  </ClientRequest>
  <Install/>
  <Types/>
  <LR/>
  <Package/>
  <Services/>
  <Issues/>
  <Complaints/>
</Response>
```

Note also that you could wrap either of the above XPaths in `boolean()` or `count()` to return an indicator or count of the presence of such populated elements.